# Get Number and Name From Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, e-commerce

I've created an array that contains the elements of an order:

Array ( [0] => M8 [1] => M8 [2] => U- ) 
(it gets the first 2 chars from the title in the foreach loop - its all i need)

I need to know how many M8's come up in this array.

basically if they buy 2 or more M8's then they get a free item. But if they buy 1 M8 and a U- they get nothing.

There will also be other products too:

Array ( [0] => M8 [1] => M8 [2] => U- [3] => D8)

if they buy an M8 and a D8 they get a free item as well

so its not just based off quantity its based off how many items they buy and the product ID (m8,d8 ect..)

a free item with any d8 and m8 purchase, or free item with any 2 d8 or and 2 m8

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for that:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Should return an array like array('M8' => 2, 'U-' => 1, etc. etc.)

Edit: For example.

```
<?php
$counts = array_count_values($input);
if(isset($counts['M8']) && $counts['M8'] >= 2)
{
   //Do special things when 2 M8's are present.
}
```